# Mongodb How can I stop shutdown one of instances

Tags: mongodb

I'm a newbie to Mongodb. I installed Mongodb 3.4 and setup two config files each config has different port and share a same ip address. How can I shut down instance in mongoA.conf file. Try to use command "sudo service mongod stop" But it doesn't know which config file to stop the service.  Thanks in advance

start two instances Mongodb config files:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongoA.conf
mongod --config /etc/mongoB.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find PID of mongod port. Then kill process on that PID.

To find all PID mongod, type:

```
# ps -aux | grep mongod
```

You will see on console:

```
root     28035  0.9 18.5 5319648 2992608 ?     Sl   Apr06 1493:14 mongod --config /etc/mongoA.conf
```

Then kill process on this PID:

```
# sudo kill -9 NUMBER_PID
```

On above example, NUMBER_PID is 28035.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX `ps -alx` will give the same list of processes.

If you allow `kill` to send the default TERM signal by not using `-9` explicitly it will allow the database to catch the TERM signal and shutdown cleanly.